# Jquery get height of fluid image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to get the height of an image and apply the height to another div. This is easy using

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var img_height = $('#image').height(); 
    $('.some_div').css('height', img_height);
});
```

however... the image is set to width 100% and changes size when re-sizing the browser window. Is it possible to get the live height of the image?

Comment: IIRC $.height() returns the current computed height of the element... so have you tried calling $('#image').height() and echoing the result to the console on $(window).on('resize') or similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(window).resize(function () {
  var image_height = $('img').height();
  $('div').css({
      'height': image_height
  });
});
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hannigan/ztCdQ/) which uses the Console to report back the image height.

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't really work well due to the way jsfiddle works, but good answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window `resize` callback

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var img_height = $('#image').height(); 
    $('.some_div').css('height', img_height);
})
```